# select user whose child is less than 2

Tags: mysql

i have table structure like this

| id | user_id | parent_id | club |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  | club1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | club1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | club1 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | club1 |
| 5 | 5 | 2 | club1 |
| 6 | 6 | 3 | club1 |
| 7 | 7 | 3 | club1 |
| 8 | 8 | 4 | club1 |
| 9 | 9 | 4 | club1 |
| 10 | 10 | 5 | club1 |
| 11 | 11 | 5 | club1 |
| 12 | 12 | 6 | club1 |
| 13 | 13 | 6 | club1 |
| 14 | 14 | 7 | club1 |
| 15 | 15 | 7 | club1 |

i want to select user_id whose child is less then 2.
refer to above table user 1,2,3,4,5,6 and 7 two child complete so the query  should return 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15

Refer to above table here user_id 1 have two child 2 and 3 , user_id 2 have child 4 and 5 and so on.

i need to select user_id whose child is less than 2

Comment: *but get error* Please share the error message

Comment: Please include the statement that you tried, and more details about the desired output. (I seem to have a language problem reading your description of what it should do.  It is unclear why you expect `8,9,....15` to be returned.

Comment: @Luuk updated question, i tried with the answer below but its not working to me may be due to version issue, i am using mysql 5.0

Comment: Please share the (complete) error message that you are getting, and stop guessing about what **might** be the cause of the problem.  Below SQL is  standard SQL  (no fancy stuff in that query), and should work in mysql 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM club_tree
WHERE user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT parent_id
    from club_tree
    where club = 'club1'
    group by parent_id 
    HAVING count(1) >= 2
) 
and club = 'club1';
```

We Select users that are not in the list of users with more than two childs.

This is to get users with more than two childs :

```
SELECT parent_id
    from club_tree
    group by parent_id 
    HAVING count(1) >= 2
```

Here you can test it : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb2c70/3

Comment: @TausifAhmad Can you recheck my answer again ?

Comment: its not working to me , may be due to vesion?

Comment: Which version of mysql you are using ?

Comment: thanks it worked, i deleted all data and created again,

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query using `left join` :

```
SELECT c.user_id
  from club_tree c
  left join 
  (
    select parent_id
    from club_tree
    where club = 'club1'
    group by parent_id 
    HAVING count(1) >= 2
  ) as c2 on c.user_id = c2.parent_id
  where c.club = 'club1' and c2.parent_id is null;
```

Try it here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb2c70/17